# How can I get all nested dependencies of a project using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am working with a project (java) , I have a pom that calls a parent pom...

That parent pom calls other poms and they call other poms. So, at the end I have a project whos pom calls other projects, so I am able to use them calling their methods and all (But I dont use. At the end, my project calls another 20 other projects with their own poms, methods, services and so on...

Between all this mess I realized my project might not be using all other projects, so, I would like to get just the right dependencies I need, take them out from the other projects and include them at my local project. Some of those included projects might call each other creating some errors.

I thought I had cleaned up this project including only the right dependencies, but then I get a `Dependency convergence error`

Is there any way I can track all dependencies used by my project and the dependencies used by my included projects(nested dependencies) all by once?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the maven-dependency-plugin? You get a list of dependencies grouped by ***Used undeclared dependencies*** or ***Unused declared dependencies***

> mvn dependency:analyze

or to see mismatches in your dependencyManagement section use:

> mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt

Also helpful is

> mvn dependency:tree

for a complete dependency tree.
You have more options, see [maven-dependency-plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) for more details.

Comment: Generally, link-only answers are frowned on

Answer (score 2):

Using the [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) plugin:

```
% mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: strategic posting and commenting does not help the community

Comment: What are you on about, @FredFelsbruckner?